# Object must return function

Tags: javascript

I have some JS code here:

```
function Car(manufacturer, model, year) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year == undefined ? new Date().getFullYear() : year;
    this.getInfo = function(){
        return this.manufacturer +' '+ this.model +' '+ this.year;
    };
}

var bmw = new Car("BMW", "X5", 2010);
```

So I want some interesting output in the console:

```
console.log('Car: ' + bmw); // Car: BMW X5 2010
```

How to do it without calling any methods?

**THANKS!**

```
I need the 'getInfo' method, so I have simply changed my code:
function Car(manufacturer, model, year) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year == undefined ? new Date().getFullYear() : year;
    this.toString = this.getInfo = function(){
        return this.manufacturer +' '+ this.model +' '+ this.year;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override your object's [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method:

```
function Car(manufacturer, model, year) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year == undefined ? new Date().getFullYear() : year;
    this.toString = function() {
        return this.manufacturer + ' ' + this.model + ' ' + this.year;
    };
}
```

You can test the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Etgx/).

Comment: So as I understood the 'toString' method is called each time I call an object?

Comment: No : only when a string representation is needed.  `"somestring"+aobject` is an example of such occurence.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'll remove the comment but I'm not the downvoter

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` just outputs to the console what it is given as a parameter. In your case, you are giving it a string (by concatenating a string with an object).

If you were to simply put `console.log(bmw)` you would see an interesting outcome - depending on which web inspector you are using, you will be able to click through all of `bmw`'s properties... very nice.

The representation of `console.log(bmw)` in Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

To answer your precise question, you can change the string representation of an object by overriding its `toString()` function.

```
function Car(manufacturer, model, year) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year == undefined ? new Date().getFullYear() : year;
    this.getInfo = function(){
        return this.manufacturer +' '+ this.model +' '+ this.year;
    };

    // Build the string up as you wish it to be represented.
    this.toString = function() {
        var str = this.manufacturer + " " + this.model + " " + this.year;
        return str;
    };
}

var bmw = new Car("BMW", "X5", 2010);
console.log('Car: ' + bmw); // Car: BMW X5 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

You may override the `toString` method :

```
Car.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.model + ' ' + this.year;
};
```

This method is automatically called when a string representation of the object is needed (for example when you do `"somestring" + yourObject`.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString